# VB.NET Image array using project resources

Tags: vb.net, arrays, image

I need to make an array of images using references to the resources folder.

The following is my code which does not work:

```
Dim imgPictures(8) As Image
imgPictures(0) = Image.FromFile(My.Resources.cat_1.ToString)
```

How do I reference the images sitting in the resouces folder for this task?

Cheers

Comment: You are having images in the resources, so to get the images dynamically, there is a GetImage method which you can use in a loop.

Image img = My.Resource.GetImage("ResourceKey_<Index>");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim imgPictures(8) As Image
imgPictures(0) = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("myResourceName")
```

...

```
' For assigning a resource to a image control based on your array 
' of strings use something  like this:

Me.picture1.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(arr(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `My.Resource.GetString("ResourceKey{0}")` method for it.

Comment: I don't understand the implementation for this in an Image array

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to reference a Resource in code is to add it to the project resources.

- Right click on the project and choose Properties
- Select the Resources Tab
- Change the Combo Box to Images
- Select the "Add Existing" Image from the Add Resource Combo Button
- Choose your Image

You can then reference the image directly in code using the following

```
Dim img = My.Resources.NameOfTheImage
```

Comment: I don't understand the implementation for this in an Image array

Answer (score 0):

I think JaredPar was on the right track, but a little more info is needed.

In essence, it kind of depends on how the resources are stored.  (If you are looking to get the path of a resource, you will most likely have to look into reflection.)

---

If your images are embedded or content you can reference them directly:

-(Right Click Image in Visual Studio > Properties > Build Action = "Embedded Resource"

-(Right Click Image in Visual Studio > Properties > Build Action = "Content"; also ensure Copy To Output Directory = "Copy Always")

```
Dim imgPictures(8) As Image
imgPictures(0) = My.Resources.NameOfImage1
imgPictures(1) = My.Resources.NameOfImage2
...
```

If your images are just in a folder:

```
Dim imgPictures(8) As Image
imgPictures(0) = Bitmap.FromFile( <filename1> )
imgPictures(1) = Bitmap.FromFile( <filename2> )
...
```

Scott